# Overriding equals and hashcode for a Triplet Class In java

Tags: java, class, overriding, equals, hashcode

I have a Triple class which is a class which can contain 3 integers (x,y,z). I want to override the equals/hashcode methods so that they can be used in a set. So an obj with (1,2,3) should be equal to (3,2,1) or (3,1,2) and so should be equal to any of it's permutation. I know how to do this for a Pair class with (x,y) - the code for a pair class I have for this is:

```
class Pair {
    int x;
    int y;

    public Pair(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        if(obj instanceof  Pair) {
            Pair p = (Pair) obj;

            if (this.x == p.x && p.y == this.y || this.x == p.y && this.y == p.x) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Integer.hashCode(x) * Integer.hashCode(y);
    }
}
```

This works fine but if I want to extend this to a Triple class, I know I can edit the equals method and add more conditions to check but this seems really long. Is there any way I can do this without using external libraries in Java?

Comment: Why does it seem really long?

Comment: Your equals method *does not* compare permutations.

Comment: However, here is a hint to make it "shorter". You could have a method called `asList()` in your `Triplet` class which returns the three elements as a list and do `return this.asList().containsAll(other.asList())` - But I think this is a horrible way to solve the issue. The good way is to use `if`s and check all the necessary conditions.

Comment: IDEs can automatically generate these methods for you if you think you have to write a lot.

Comment: Regarding your hash combine, multiply is an unnecessarily expensive computation. The common way is to use the XOR (^) operator. It is also a good choice, because the output probability distribution is 50%, assuming uniformly random inputs.

Comment: A lot of the answers here suggest computing the equals/hashCode based on sorted values, which I'd use. But consider: is it *really* meaningful to store the *unsorted* values `x`, `y` and `z`? I mean, if you're going to treat `(1,2,3)` the same as `(3,2,1)`, isn't it better just to store the sorted values only? Is there a use case for knowing that it was `(2,3,1)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution is to keep a sorted array for comparison:

```
class Triple {
    private final int x, y, z;
    private final int[] sorted;

    public Triple(int x, int y, int z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
        this.sorted = new int[] {x, y, z};
        Arrays.sort(sorted);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj instanceof Triple
                && Arrays.equals(((Triple)obj).sorted, this.sorted);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.hashCode(sorted);
    }
}
```

Comment: It could be useful to move the sorting part inside the `equals` method. If the OP is going to implement `setX`, `setY`, `setZ` methods, he would have to sort the array each time one of these methods is called. If you move the sorting inside the equals it should make things lighter, as you sort just one time when you need to.

Comment: "If the OP is going to implement setX, setY, setZ methods", better yet don't and keep `Triple` immutable

Comment: @BackSlash I assumed the class is immutable (note the `final` modifiers). If it's not, you would have to sort them on every call to `equals()` or `hashCode()`, which I would definitely want to avoid.

Comment: @shmosel Yes, I noticed, but the original class posted by the OP doesn't have `final` fields, that's the reason of my comment. He should actually clarify if he needs the class to be immutable or not.

Comment: @SteveKuo This really depends on the OP's needs. If he needs the Triple to be mutable, it's perfectly fine to have it mutable. (and since he didn't say he needs it to be immutable...) Anyway, as previously said, it's something the OP needs to clarify

Comment: @Kevin Perhaps not a major bottleneck, but it's hard to say for sure, especially if it needs to scale (in size or quantity). Also, mutable keys is asking for trouble in general.

Comment: @Kevin 3 numbers per triplet, but to be multiplied by the number of triplets. If you have many objects in the `Set`it can become quite heavy. But I agree with shmosel, keys should stay immutable.

Answer (score 0):

To check the combinations, you can add the elements into `list` and invoke `containsAll` method to check the equality, e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,2,4});
    List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{4,2,1});
    System.out.println(list1.containsAll(list2) && list2.containsAll(list1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer depends on how you'd want to use this class, if equality and hashCode needs to be inexpensive, then consider initialising an array on construction that can be easily compared. Something like this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Triple {
    // Use this array only for hashCode & equals.
    private final int[] values;
    private final int x;
    private final int y;
    private final int z;

    public Triple(int x, int y, int z) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.z = z;
        this.values = new int[]{x, y, z};
        // Sort the values for simpler comparison of equality.
        Arrays.sort(values);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        Triple triple = (Triple) o;
        return Arrays.equals(values, triple.values);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Arrays.hashCode(values);
    }
}
```

Added some tests to prove equality and non equality:

```
import static org.hamcrest.core.Is.is;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsEqual.equalTo;
import static org.hamcrest.core.IsNot.not;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

public class TripleTest {

    @Test
    public void valuesInDifferentOrderAreEqual() {
        Triple sortedTriple = new Triple(1, 2, 3);
        Triple outOfOrderTriple = new Triple(3, 2, 1);
        Assert.assertThat(sortedTriple, equalTo(outOfOrderTriple));
        Assert.assertThat(sortedTriple.hashCode(), is(outOfOrderTriple.hashCode()));
    }

    @Test
    public void valuesInOrderAreEqual() {
        Triple sortedTriple = new Triple(1, 2, 3);
        Triple outOfOrderTriple = new Triple(1, 2, 3);
        Assert.assertThat(sortedTriple, equalTo(outOfOrderTriple));
        Assert.assertThat(sortedTriple.hashCode(), is(outOfOrderTriple.hashCode()));
    }

    @Test
    public void valuesThatAreDifferentAreNotEqual() {
        Triple sortedTriple = new Triple(1, 2, 3);
        Triple outOfOrderTriple = new Triple(7, 8, 9);
        Assert.assertThat(sortedTriple, not(outOfOrderTriple));
        Assert.assertThat(sortedTriple.hashCode(), not(outOfOrderTriple.hashCode()));
    }

    @Test
    public void valuesWithSameSumAreNotEqual() {
        Triple sortedTriple = new Triple(11, 21, 31);
        Triple outOfOrderTriple = new Triple(36, 12, 21);
        Assert.assertThat(sortedTriple, not(outOfOrderTriple));
        Assert.assertThat(sortedTriple.hashCode(), not(outOfOrderTriple.hashCode()));
    }

    @Test
    public void valuesWithSameProductAreNotEqual() {
        Triple sortedTriple = new Triple(11, 21, 31);
        Triple outOfOrderTriple = new Triple(33, 7, 31);
        Assert.assertThat(sortedTriple, not(outOfOrderTriple));
        Assert.assertThat(sortedTriple.hashCode(), not(outOfOrderTriple.hashCode()));
    }
}
```